# How to add background photos/text in the folder view on windows by shell namespace extension

Tags: c++, windows, shell-extensions, shell-namespace-extension

I used miscrosoft SDK sample to create a virtual folder by shell namespace extension:
[image]

In this virtual folder, it has several folders. One of the folders is empty.
I want to change the background for the empty folder's folder view, like:
[image]

SO for folders who contain files, display the files, but for the empty folder, display "No files in this folder".
Is there any way to do that?
I am thinking maybe I can PS a photo which contains the text and display the photo as the background photo for the empty folder.
But how to do that?
In SDK sample code, they just use the default folder view:

```
class CFolderViewCB : public IShellFolderViewCB,
public IFolderViewSettings
{
public:
CFolderViewCB() : _cRef(1) { }

// IUnknown
IFACEMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv)
{
    static const QITAB qit[] =
    {
        QITABENT(CFolderViewCB, IShellFolderViewCB),
        QITABENT(CFolderViewCB, IFolderViewSettings),
        { 0 },
    };
    return QISearch(this, qit, riid, ppv);
}

IFACEMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef() { return InterlockedIncrement(&_cRef); }
IFACEMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release()
{
    long cRef = InterlockedDecrement(&_cRef);
    if (0 == cRef)
    {
        delete this;
    }
    return cRef;
}

// IShellFolderViewCB
IFACEMETHODIMP MessageSFVCB(UINT /* uMsg */, WPARAM /* wParam */, LPARAM /* lParam */)
{   
        return E_NOTIMPL;   
}

// IFolderViewSettings
IFACEMETHODIMP GetColumnPropertyList(REFIID /* riid */, void **ppv)
{
    *ppv = NULL; return E_NOTIMPL;
}
IFACEMETHODIMP GetGroupByProperty(PROPERTYKEY * /* pkey */, BOOL * /* pfGroupAscending */)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}
IFACEMETHODIMP GetViewMode(FOLDERLOGICALVIEWMODE * /* plvm */)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}
IFACEMETHODIMP GetIconSize(UINT * /* puIconSize */)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

IFACEMETHODIMP GetFolderFlags(FOLDERFLAGS *pfolderMask, FOLDERFLAGS *pfolderFlags);

IFACEMETHODIMP GetSortColumns(SORTCOLUMN * /* rgSortColumns */, UINT /* cColumnsIn */, UINT * /* pcColumnsOut */)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}
IFACEMETHODIMP GetGroupSubsetCount(UINT * /* pcVisibleRows */)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

private:
~CFolderViewCB() { };
long _cRef;
};

// IFolderViewSettings
IFACEMETHODIMP CFolderViewCB::GetFolderFlags(FOLDERFLAGS *pfolderMask, 
FOLDERFLAGS *pfolderFlags)
{
if (pfolderMask)
{
    *pfolderMask = FWF_USESEARCHFOLDER;
}

if (pfolderFlags)
{
    *pfolderFlags = FWF_USESEARCHFOLDER;
}

return S_OK;
}

HRESULT CFolderViewCB_CreateInstance(REFIID riid, void **ppv)
{
*ppv = NULL;

HRESULT hr = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
CFolderViewCB *pfvcb = new (std::nothrow) CFolderViewCB();
if (pfvcb)
{
    hr = pfvcb->QueryInterface(riid, ppv);
    pfvcb->Release();
}
return hr;
}
```

---------------------------Update------------------------------

```
IFACEMETHODIMP MessageSFVCB(UINT  uMsg , WPARAM  wParam , LPARAM  lParam )
{

    std::basic_string<TCHAR> test = L"no items";

    if (uMsg == 54)
    {
        lParam = LPARAM(test.c_str());
    }

    wParam = 10;

    return S_OK;
}
```

Based on @DenisAnisimov 's comments, when I revise the function to the above code.But it doesn't work. When I click  the folder, the windows explorer is not responding and then crash.
------------------------update 2nd-------------------------------

```
//test is a global variable of string, std::string test = "no items";
 IFACEMETHODIMP MessageSFVCB(UINT  uMsg , WPARAM  wParam , LPARAM  lParam )
 {
    if (uMsg == 54)
    {
        lParam = reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&test);

        wParam = sizeof(test);

        return S_OK;
    }
    return E_NOTIMPL; 
}
```

or

```
// test is char test[9] = "no items";
IFACEMETHODIMP MessageSFVCB(UINT  uMsg , WPARAM  wParam , LPARAM  lParam )
{
    if (uMsg == 54)
    {
        lParam = reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&test);

        wParam = strlen(test);
        return S_OK;
    }
    return E_NOTIMPL; 
}
```

or

```
// test is char test[9] = "no items"; 
IFACEMETHODIMP MessageSFVCB(UINT  uMsg , WPARAM  wParam , LPARAM  lParam )
{
    if (uMsg == 54)
    {
        lParam = LPARAM(test);

        wParam = strlen(test);

        return S_OK;
    }
    return E_NOTIMPL; 
}
```

or

```
// test is char test[9] = "no items";
IFACEMETHODIMP MessageSFVCB(UINT  uMsg , WPARAM  wParam , LPARAM  lParam )
{
    test[8] = '\0';

    if (uMsg == 54)
    {
        lParam = LPARAM(test);

        wParam = strlen(test);

        return S_OK;
    }
    return E_NOTIMPL; 
}
```

This time the empty folder displays still nothing, no any strings as the background.
-----------------------------update 3rd------------------

```
IFACEMETHODIMP MessageSFVCB(UINT  uMsg , WPARAM  /*wParam*/ , LPARAM  lParam )
{
    char a[9] = "no items";
    a[8] = '\0';
    if (uMsg == 54)
    {
        char* s = (char*)lParam;

        memcpy(s, a, strlen(a));

        char* tt = (char*)lParam;

        s = tt;

        return S_OK;
    }
    return E_NOTIMPL; 
}
```

or

```
IFACEMETHODIMP MessageSFVCB(UINT  uMsg , WPARAM  /*wParam*/ , LPARAM  lParam )
{
    char* a = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);

    memset(a, 0, sizeof(char) * 10);

    a = "no items";


    if (uMsg == 54)
    {
        char* s = (char*)lParam;

        memcpy(s, a, strlen(a));

        char* tt = (char*)lParam;

        s = tt;

        return S_OK;
    }
    return E_NOTIMPL; 
}
```

This time I debug it by add breakpoint to `char* tt = (char*)lParam;`, `tt` does becomes "no items".
But it displays wrong string in the background:

[image]

---------------------------final update -----------------
This time it works!

```
//wchar_t test[9] = L"no items";
IFACEMETHODIMP MessageSFVCB(UINT  uMsg , WPARAM  /*wParam*/ , LPARAM  lParam )
{

    if (uMsg == 54)
    {
        wchar_t* s = (wchar_t*)lParam;

        memcpy(s, test, 18);
        return S_OK;
    }
    return E_NOTIMPL; 
}
```

Comment: Defview allows you to print any text as empty message. First variant - SFVM_GETEMPTYTEXT, second - IFolderView2.SetText.

Comment: @DenisAnisimov  Do you mean the CFolderViewCB should be inherited from IFolderView2? Based on my understanding, I need CFolderViewCB to be inherited from IShellView type class. So IFolderView2 is inherited from IShellView?

Comment: So IFolderView2 is inherited from IShellView? Or do you mean I call IFolderView2 in MessageSFVCB?

Comment: I mean you can process SFVM_GETEMPTYTEXT inside your MessageSFVCB, OR you can query defview for IFolderView2 and call SetText.

Comment: @DenisAnisimov based on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774968(v=vs.85).aspx ,there is no SFVM_GETEMPTYTEXT

Comment: And after I add switch(uMsg) {case SFVCB: break;}, how could I implement the action of setting the string to "No items"?

Comment: SFVM_GETEMPTYTEXT is undocumented but there are a lot of info about SFVM_GETEMPTYTEXT in Google. LParam - pointer to buffer, WParam - buffer len (in chars). Just copy your string info buffer and return S_OK. SFVM_GETEMPTYTEXT = 54.

Comment: @DenisAnisimov Sorry, I googled SFVM_GETEMPTYTEXT but I got nothing.... Google cannot find any related info.

Comment: 1) You must COPY your string into buffer. 2) You must return S_OK ONLY if you process the message. In your case you must return S_OK ONLY if uMsg == 54, in all other cases you must return E_NOTIMPL.

Comment: @DenisAnisimov Still no string shows up in the background, can you see my update 2nd please?

Comment: In all your variants you just set lparam. It is not correct. LParam is pointer to buffer and you must COPY your string into this buffer. You should not change wparam or lparam at all.

Comment: @DenisAnisimov it displays some random characters after I copy my string into lParam, can you see my update 3rd please ?

Comment: It looks like you copy ansi string instead of unicode.

Comment: @DenisAnisimov Thank you so much! It works this time when I change it to wchar_t .

Answer (score 0):

When you're called on [IShellFolder::CreateViewObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775064.aspx) for IID_IShellView, you can return a custom [IShellView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774834.aspx) implementation (you must also implement [IOleWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680102.aspx)), instead of the default one (usually got from calling the SHCreateShellFolderView function).

Your custom implementation only needs to implement `CreateViewWindow`, `DestroyViewWindow`, and IOleWindow's `GetWindow` methods for a start (for other methods, you can return E_NOTIMPL)

Comment: So any sample code of implementing CreateViewWindow? It is not like MFC to just simply add a LTEXT control to the dialog.

Comment: @beasone - You asked how to do it. This is how to do it. I don't have a sample available but google may help.